# Google analytics in React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, statistics

How to implement Google Analytics on `onCLick` events? using react-ga module or some other similar modules.

E.g. if a website has search feature, say i want to search customer id or item id and, i want to track the search events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code it's hard to help you out and see how this solution fits in your project, but one way to do it is using ReactGa.

On the page you need the function import the reactGa

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
```

Next create a function to handle the event

```
const eventTrack = (category, action, label) => {
  console.log("GA event:", category, ":", action, ":", label);
  ReactGA.event({
    category: category,
    action: action,
    label: label,
  })
}
```

now attach the event to the button

```
<button type="submit" className="search" onClick={eventTrack.bind(this, 
"category", "Action", "Label")}>search</button>
```

this should get you on the way, you'll need to supply props for the search terms. By implementing the code you should be able to see the console.log and see exactly what get's logged.

On the [ReactGa github](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga), there is some great examples of using the component